# civicrm_handler_filter_participant_role.inc

Tags: issues

this file is missing from the latest civicrm

\sites\all\modules\civicrm\drupal\modules\views\civicrm\civicrm_handler_filter_participant_role.inc

Is this intentially missing? We have functionality that depends on the sql rewrites and need to know if civicrm will be resolving this or if we need to implement our own custom code to provide this functionality

Comment: which version did you have this file in?

Comment: the drupal version of the module is version 4.1

Comment: Hmm, I looked at a new download of that version of the civicrm module and it doesn't have that file. It seems that civi on this project has been "customized"

Answer (score 2):

Hmm, I looked at a new download of that version of the civicrm module and it doesn't have that file. It seems that civi on this project has been "customized"